# ansible role: Why do I have to set user.email in etckeeper?

Tags: git, ansible, etckeeper

I wrote [a ansible role to automate installing `etckeeper`](https://github.com/sourcejedi/ansible-etckeeper).

I discover that git will complain if I haven't configured user.email.  In some circumstances, git commits will fail.  This includes automatic commits to etckeeper when installing a package, potentially causing the install to fail.  So I have to add a task for that, like [everyone else does :)](https://github.com/debops-contrib/ansible-etckeeper/blob/b56cc3496c76c3e2d44322748f3efa5422baa980/tasks/main.yml#L85).

The frustrating thing is that in some circumstances, it seemed to work ok.  And it doesn't seem to be a problem when using etckeeper manually.  `user.email` is never mentioned in the [tutorial](https://etckeeper.branchable.com/README/).

Is it actually necessary to set `user.email` in the Ansible role?  If so... there must be *some* deliberate reason(s) causing this.  Some explanation, which I could put into a comment in the role, or which would justify a patch to etckeeper or git?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE: should be fixed in the next release (1.18.8).

https://etckeeper.branchable.com/todo/requires___96__user.email__96___be_set_under_undocumented_circumstances/

---

After hitting this a couple of times, I felt I needed to look at the source code.

1. git absolutely requires an "email address" for its commits.  Without one, it will refuse to make a commit.
2. git will "autodetect" an email, if the system hostname can be resolved to a Fully Qualified Domain Name.  (You must have at least one `.` to qualify :).  Or, if `/etc/mailname` exists, it uses that by preference, without checking for `.`s.
3. etckeeper tries to pass an email address to git, constructed from a username and the system hostname.  git will accept such explicitly-specified emails, even if the host part is not an FQDN.  If `sudo` is used, etckeeper uses SUDO_USER from the environment.  In case `su` is used, there is nothing in the environment, and so etckeeper reads the user from the owner of the [tty](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tty.1.html).

So `git commit` and `etckeeper vcs commit` failed, when I hadn't set `user.email`, AND my hostname did not resolve to an FQDN.

`etckeeper commit` works in some situations that `git commit` doesn't.  I believe I got confused between these two when I was testing before (among other things).

If you run `etckeeper` from `sudo`, it won't fail.  If you run it from `su`, it won't fail.  It won't fail either if you log in as root and run it; it will find a tty which is owned by root, and pass an email of `root@HOSTNAME`.

`etckeeper commit` will fail if and only if

1. `user.email` is not set in `git`, AND
2. the system hostname cannot be resolved to an FQDN, AND
3. /etc/mailname does not exist (it is created by the Debian exim packages?) AND
4. etckeeper is not run from sudo AND
5. etckeeper is not run from a tty

Finally, testing indicated that commands run under ansible are never run from a tty.  (Even when using an `ssh` connection and `sudo` with a password, where ansible is described as [needing to use a pseudo-tty](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/14377)).